# PHP doctrine convers enum to varchar while generating the db from schema?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I am generating db from my schema file. I have written following column for my priority field:
priority: { type: enum(20), values: [ 'show stopper', high, medium, low ],  notnull: true }

But, when I browse to my phpmyadmin, it only shows me the type of priority is varchar(20).
So I am facing the problem in sorting.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: ENUMs are evil: http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/ Consider changing your data to a lookup table instead.

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine doesnt support enum types . so it will automatically be converted to varchar 
http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/cookbook/mysql-enums.html